# Selective reflection based on material in cycles

Tags: rendering, materials

I've done some searching but can't find anything on this.
Is it possible to dictate what is reflected in an object based on it's material rather than the usual object based settings such as the layer and visibility settings? I have 2 x domes. They have almost identical materials except for their emission strength setting of the image texture they both share. The brighter dome lights my scene and provides reflection for *most* of the objects in the scene. But the reflection of this brighter dome is too powerful for just one particular glass material. I wondered if I can make this glass material reflect the less bright dome instead?